# Image slideshow only for mobile users?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, slideshow

I have one question, is there anyway I could make a slideshow of images for mobile users only and when viewed in ex desktops and tablets to show the images in a order and not in a slideshow

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, display the images in order and hide your slideshow with the [display css property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

```
.mySlideshowContainer {
    display: none;
}
```

Then include conditional css rules with [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) depending on the resolution or the size of the client device.

In those rules, display the slideshow and hide the images shown in order using the css display property again.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your slidshow by adding display property to the class containing slideshow

```
 display:none;
```

and by using media queries you can show slideshow by adding

```
display:initial;
```

css

```
 .class-name{
   display:none;
   }
```

and if you want to display the slide show on smaller screens like width 640 or less
use the media query

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
 .class-name{
  display:initial;
  }
```